# Why isn't there a unified logic?

Tags: logic

It seems that there are numerous systems of logic. Why didn't we just combine them all into one and get the best of all worlds? Like we could combine axiomatic reasoning and analogical reasoning into one unified logic and get the best of all worlds. Why don't we do this?

Comment: Short answer: 1. Because different logics make different claims about what is true; there is a point to having multiple systems depending on what one believes in or wants to have for the current purpose and what not. 2. Because the different claims that different logics make partially are in direct opposition to each other; there is no straightforward way to just "merge" all these into one without getting contradictions (for which one would have to decide if they are a problem).

Comment: @lemontree Thanks this is interesting. I'm picking up logic now. It seems you could combine axiomatic logic and analogy logic, for example. Are you saying there are trade-offs in logic systems? That's why we have different ones? Like there is a No Free Lunch Theorem for logic systems?

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: By Graham Priest a reknown logician that advocates " alternative" logics : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVJ2vTa3CVnS8VVn20qOwfUyOdkyhBN_k

Comment: Because the fundamental notion of axiomatic systems have hidden incoherence that no one has untangled yet. As soon as people realize that axiomatic systems can be comprised of semantic logical entailments that have corresponding formal proofs the notation of axiomatic systems can be unified.

Comment: One of the main "divide" is that between [Classical](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/) and [Intuitionistic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/): the difference is to accept/reject LEM ? In what way can we "combine them" ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Some expressions of language are true: "existence exists", some are false: "existence does not exist", and some are neither: "Does existence exist?"

Comment: @polcott - "Existence exists" ????

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA " "Existence exists" ????" is the one thing that has the most logically justified certainty. Like René Descartes "I think therefore I am" merely asking the question conclusively proves the result.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Any attempt to prove that existence does not exist would be self-refutational, (because it would form an example of a thing that exists thus a counter-example to the claim that "existence does not exist" ). This makes the assertion that "existence exists" is irrefutable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA LEM only applies to correct propositions and forms the basis to decide that a proposition is incorrect. Expressions of language that cannot possibly be resolved to exactly one of: {True, False} are not a correct logical propositions. In mathematical logic, a sentence of a predicate logic is a boolean-valued well-formed formula with no free variables. A sentence can be viewed as expressing a proposition, something that must be true or false. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(mathematical_logic)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA on this basis Intuitionistic logic is decided to be merely incomplete and nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because the different claims that different logics make partially are in direct opposition to each other, and **it is not possible to just "merge" all these into one without immediately getting contradictions**, for sure on the meta level (i.e. "This axiom holds" vs. "This axiom doesn't hold"), and possibly even among the axioms themselves on the object level ("This formula is valid" vs. "The negation of this formula is valid"). For example, classical logic claims that the law of the excluded middle holds, intuitionistic logic claims that it doesn't. Now what? What is the "correct" unification of these opposing claims? Which leads us to the next problem:
2. Because **it is not easy to see how such a unification would work**. Simply taking the union of all axioms will always override logics with fewer axioms and give you the one that has all these axioms already incorporated. Taking half of the axioms in and excluding others leaves the question of which axioms to pick. Then there may not be formulations in terms of axioms for all logics at all, and whether an axiomatic approach is the most suitable is also debatable. One could consider as a basis rules for calculi such as natural deduction, but will run into similar problems. Taking a purely semantic approach is even more problematic because different logics use entirely different ontologies to define their semantics; for instance, there are no truth tables in intuitionistic and minimal logic. Unifying the set of conclusions triggers the same problem as unifying the set of axioms but mirrored -- e.g., the conclusions valid in intuitionistic logic are a proper subset of the conclusions of classical logic, so taking the union of the intuitionistic theorems and the classical theorems will simply yield classical logic again, and not any interesting compromise. So how to even formulate that new unified logic and then which laws to pick up into that construction is not at all a trivial problem. And whether a mashed-together system that is watered down enough to incorporate every logic system in existence will still do sufficient justice to the original systems and any intuitive appeal is even more questionable. **Logics are just too different** to be stirred together in a meaningful way.
3. Because, most importantly, the whole point of having different systems of logic in the first place is that they make different claims about what is true, and depending on what one believes in or wants to hold in order for a particular system to work, one will want to choose that logic which suits one's needs best.  **Pluralism is not a bad thing**; it exists so different requirements can be satisfied, because, as said, different logics suited for different purposes make opposing claims, so a single system will never work for everyone.

Comment: Thanks @lemontree ! Consider two setups. (1) What if you ensemble logical systems and combine their conclusions? (2) Can't you have a logic system spawn sub-logic systems?

Comment: Should there be a logic that intelligently weights each conclusion from a pluralist standpoint?

Comment: Combining the conclusions yields precisely the problem outlined in 2. that this will just have you end up  with the logcs which prove more theorems and "overwrite" logics which claim that these conclusions don't hold, which wouldn't be a fair unification. To name the most common example, the theorems of intuitionistic logic are a subset of the theorems of classical logic, so unifying the conclusions of classical logic with those of intuitionistic logic just yields classical logic, and not any interesting compromise.

Comment: Re. your second comment: Are you aiming at a probabilistic approach in which statements are assigned a "degree of truth" rather than an absolute value "true"/"false"? These kinds of logics exist, but again, it is questionable whether this is indeed a fair unification, because it contradicts the principle of most logics that truth values are bivalent.

Comment: If, instead, you are aiming to initially assign weights, then pick out definitely true and definitely false conclusions based on those weights, the question is what this intelligence does, exactly, and how to justify its choices. On what basis do you decide how much a conclusion weighs? How do you make sure that the resulting logic is still meaningful, in the way that the conclusions you decided to keep in can be derived in a systematic way, e.g. by a precisely defined set of syntactic rules?

Comment: A simplistic construction of a kind of "average" conclusions set likely will result in a logic whose underlying rules are obscure or even impossible to match the conclusions at all; but the systematic patterns from which conclusions are derived is what makes logic actually interesting.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the responses! I'm an AI researcher (not good at logic). How do we pick a logic system? We just have to assume that the underlying laws hold?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad to be simply answered within a comment. Essentially, you figure out which claims you want to hold in your logic, then try to come up with a set of rules which will produce precisely (not more, but ideally not less) these facts. Prior to that, you will have to make some basic decisions about the semantical architecture, e.g. how many truth values your semantics knows.

Comment: And lastly, some practical considerations need to be made -- for instance, if a language has more expressive power than another, it is usually also much more difficult to handle computationally. You need to find the right trade-off between your needs.

Comment: But again: This is way too broad a question to be answered within a few sentences. If you want to get more into the topic, I suggest you read up on some non-standard logics; this will put you in a better position to understand what different logics can look like and why bringing them together isn't so easy. My recommendation is "An introduction to non-classical logic : from if to is" by Graham Priest. This should be readable enough if you have a basic logic bacground.

Comment: Thanks. One big question I have. It seems like there a thousand different logics. Is this normal? Are logics like programming languages?

Comment: Doesn't strong inference also suggest that we need multiple logic systems to agree ?

Comment: Here is a tougher question: Why can't a single unified system of logic be conceived? MauroALLEGRANZA proposes that we must find some way to definitely accept or reject the law of the excluded middle.

Comment: asdfasfasdgf: "Normal" compared to what? Every science has a multitude of different theories or frameworks for different purposes or different beliefs, so sure, this is nothing abnormal.  
As for your second question, I don't know what you mean by "strong inference", and again, I suggest asking new questions in a new thread; comments are not for extended discussion.
@polcott: This is what I attempted to answer in my post.

Comment: This has been my area of primary research for quite a few years. The correct notion of a formal system always maps to its logic sentences {true, false}, or not a well formed logic sentence. Thus once and for all correctly defining the law of the excluded middle. Formal systems that diverge from this model are incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is that there is no guarantee in the Soundness of such a logic!

Here’s an example. In classical logic, we know that if A is true, then it follows that A OR B is true. We also know that if A AND B is true, then it follows that B is true.

So, for some logical connectives /*, it is an admissible rule in some deductive frameworks that A -> A/*B, and for some that A/*B -> B.

However, it is important to note that these two cannot be admissible at the same time! Why not? Because if that were the case then we’d get Explosion from the transitivity of implication: for any A and B, A->B.

Unfortunately, we cannot so easily pick and choose rules of inference from different logical systems, since there is every possibility we might prove the whole scheme radically inconsistent.

Comment: Hi Sofie, thanks for the response! What does "soundness" of a logic system mean? Like whether the conclusions actually describe the true nature of the world?

Comment: I just realized that I misread your answer; sorry about that. I deleted my comment, but can't undo the downvote unless the post is edited.